# What does ‘Q’ mean for unsigned fixed-point number representation?

Tags: binary, numbers, fixed-point

The standard for an arbitrary unsigned fixed-point number is denoted as UQm.n

Presumably, the U stands for “unsigned”, but what does Q stand for?